# Calculating Time Differences

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I tried using `DateTime` in PHP and used `diff` method to find the time difference between a timestamp and the current time. However PHP gives me the wrong difference. Can anyone point out to me what went wrong in my code? Thanks!

**PHP Code**

```
function time() {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $later = new DateTime('2011-10-17 07:08:00');
    $interval = $now->diff($later);
    echo $now->format('y m d');
    echo "<br>";
    echo $later->format('y m d');
    echo "<br>";
    echo $interval->format('%a');
}
```

**Output**

```
11 10 19
11 10 17
6015
```

The difference is obviously 2 days, but I get 6015 days!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `$now->diff($now);`, should be `$now->diff($later)`.

Comment: nice catch ! Sadly I got stuck trying this code on PHP 5.2 :( Fatal error http://codepad.org/aHVVr065

Comment: Thanks! I corrected it and now it still gives 6015 as the difference!

Comment: echo $interval->format('%a'); changed to be echo $interval->format('%d');

Answer (score 0):

as written, the result should be 0,
because you are doing $now->diff($now)

If you do $later->diff($now) you should get the expected result.